# Passing a hidden field to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I need to pass in the selector a hidden field to a javascript function.

This is my function

```
function deleteAttachments(id,selector){
            $('#proof' + id).remove();
            //show warning about save
            var tmp = selector.val();
            var sep = "";
            if (tmp != "")
                sep = ",";
            selector.val(tmp + sep + id);
        }
```

The above function call is inside the following method,

```
 function listAttachments(proofs,selector,hiddenField,after){

            //alert(hiddenField.id);
            var rows = "<table width=\"70%\">";
            for(var i=0; i<proofs.length; i++) {
                var proof = proofs[i];
                rows += "<tr id=\"proof" + proof["ID"] + "\" width=\"40%\">"
                rows += "<td><input type=\"hidden\" value=\"" + proof["filename"] + "\" id=\"Proof" + i + "\" />Uploaded: " + proof["uploaded"] + "</td>"
                rows += "<td width=\"90px\"><input type=\"button\" value=\"View...\" onclick=\"viewProof('" + proof["URL"] + "'); \" id=\"btnProof" + i + "\" class=\"btn\"></td>"
                rows += "<td width=\"90px\"><input type=\"button\" value=\"Delete\" id=\"btnDelete" + i + "\" onclick=\"deleteAttachments(" + proof["ID"] + "," + hiddenField + ");\" class=\"btn\"/></td></tr>";
            }
            rows += "</table>";
            if(after){
                selector.after(rows);
            }else{
                selector.html(rows);
            }       
        }
```

Please find the `listAttachments` function calls (I am using asp.net and tried different ways) below,

```
listAttachments(visualIds,$('#tblProofs'),$('#hidDeletedAttachments'),true)
```

or

```
listAttachments(visualIds,$('#tblProofs'),$('#' + <%= hidDeletedAttachments.ID%>'),true)
```

When this is rendered the `deleteAttachments` function accepts the argument as an object (as displayed in the image below).

My question is how I can pass the selector to the function and use it with in the calling function.

[image]

Comment: Usualy I pass to functions selectors 'id', and make 'selector' inside function. Try pass arguments to function, and make selector inside function (depending on that arguments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the selector, you are passing a collection of elements that match the selector.

Instead of passing the hiddenField to listAttachments, pass the hiddenField id.

```
listAttachments(visualIds,$('#tblProofs'), 'hidDeletedAttachments'),true)
```

Then create the object in the deleteAttachment function

```
function deleteAttachments(id,hiddenFieldId){
        var selector = $('#' + hiddenFieldId);
        $('#proof' + id).remove();
        //show warning about save
        var tmp = selector.val();
        var sep = "";
        if (tmp != "")
            sep = ",";
        selector.val(tmp + sep + id);
    }
```